# Php Quickbooks Customer_Mod

Tags: php, quickbooks

I am working on Quickbooks web connector and Customer Add works very well. Now I want to modify my customer and here is my xml.

```
<QBXML>
 <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
<CustomerModRq requestID="'.$requestID.'">
  <CustomerMod>
    <ListID>ConsoliBYTE, LLC (13912179)</ListID>
    <EditSequence>1365684445</EditSequence>

    <Name>Test Customer UPDATED</Name>

  </CustomerMod>
</CustomerModRq>
</QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

The logged error is
`3000: The given object ID "ConsoliBYTE, LLC (13912179)" in the field "list id" is invalid.`

What is the list id and how do i get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `<ListID>` is an internal identifier (e.g. primary key) used by QuickBooks to identify a record.

An `<EditSequence>` is a value which indicates when the last change was made to the record. Every time the record is updated (regardless of whether this happens through the UI, or API/SDK), the `EditSequence` value changes. To update a record, you must provide the very latest `EditSequence` value.

The value you provided for `ListID` is definitely not correct. You provided a customer name, not a ListID.

Whenever you add or query for a customer, the `ListID` value and the `EditSequence` value will  will be returned.

To do an update, you should query for the customer first (to get the latest `EditSequence` value from QuickBooks) and then do your `CustomerMod` request using those latest values.

If you're using this open-source QuickBooks PHP DevKit:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php

Then you should have request/response functions written to query for customers and update customers. Queue up a `QUICKBOOKS_QUERY_CUSTOMER` and when you get back the response, queue up your `QUICKBOOKS_MOD_CUSTOMER` request then, either storing the `ListID` and `EditSequence` in `$extra` or in your own database somewhere.

Comment: Hey Keith, Even better I used the add_customer response to store the `listid` and `editsequence`, and I expect it to work.

Comment: Just be aware that if someone goes into the QuickBooks GUI, and edits the record in the GUI, the EditSequence will change and the next time you do a CustomerMod it will fail unless you fetch the new EditSequence first.

Answer (score 1):

Summarizing:

```
<ListID>13912179</ListID>
<EditSequence>1565684445</EditSequence>
```

You can see all fields possible in `CustomerModRq` [here](https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbsdk-current/common/newosr/index.html)
Both ListID & EditSequence **are crucial** to perform an update.

You **need to download the Customer** before an update in QB to see the current EditSequence value. Also you need to give **the exact value** you got from your getCustomer query in `EditSequence`. Otherwise `CustomerModRq` has no effect.